# Switch UIViewControllers beneath MDCFloatingButton

Tags: ios, material-design, material-components-ios

I want to implement the following: big circular material-style floating button (aka MDCFloatingButton) flying in the right bottom corner of the screen, and by tapping it the user can switch views beneath it. Moreover, these views should be controlled by different ViewControllers.

Is it possible? If it is, please explain how these components should be organized.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view controller that has the floating button and a container view. That container view has it's own view controller. So maybe that container view controller can be a UIPageController and you can change view controllers tapping the button, but the viewcontroller with the floating button will never leave screen. You are just changing what the container view shows.

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)